# Is the following random number generation without bias?

Tags: java, security, random

Would the following code produce a random number with or without bias?

```
    int numberToGenerate = 20;
    int rangeUpperLimit = 30;
    SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");

    for (int i = 0; i < numberToGenerate; i++) {
        int randomInt = random.nextInt(rangeUpperLimit); 
        // Do something with it.
    }
```

The values are used to pick `chars` from a `String` of length 30, hence the range 0-29. The code to pick the `char` values is omitted as it is not relevant to the question.

Comment: What is your first comment about exceptions meant to mean? Also note that `nextInt` already has an exclusive upper bound, so you should just use `rangeUpperLimit`.

Comment: Removed those and fixed the code. Thanks.

Comment: First of all, java or anyother language, does not produce a random number, its pseudo-random. Because the random class also uses some logic to produce those numbers, so its not truely random. Just an FYI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly *meant* to be a uniform distribution (and therefore without bias). From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29):

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

That assumes that the generator sequence is good, but I think that's a reasonable assumption to make here, especially given the documentation for [`SecureRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html):

> A cryptographically strong random number minimally complies with the statistical random number generator tests specified in FIPS 140-2, Security Requirements for Cryptographic Modules, section 4.9.1.

If you're concerned about bias, it would be fairly easy to check for any particular run - generate (say) thirty million values, keep track of how many times you get each number, and see how close it is to one million per bucket.

Comment: A concise and informative response. I will more than likely test the generation as well as a means for giving some level of assurance against producing a set of digits with bias. Now for me to think of an efficient way of doing this :) Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Results *should* be enough uniform by definition from [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html), but in your example you are **not using a seed** to initialize the PNRG so it may be biased.

Comment: Why would not using a seed introduce bias? What do you mean by "mostly biased" anyway? (Also note that this is `SecureRandom`, which can use various approaches to get a good seed.)

Comment: Because the algorithm used internally by `sun.security.provider.SecureRandom` is not so throughly tested. Having a true source of unpredictability in this situation helps avoiding any potential issues. Mostly is not the correct term, I'd say may.

Comment: I still don't see why you think the randomness of the seed dictates bias. It affects security in other ways, but a prng sequence can be unbiased even if it's completely predictable.

Comment: I mean in two different executions of the program, not on the same. Of  course the same sequence won't be biased in itself, otherwise it wouldn't be uniform at all, regardless of seed.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear to me what you mean... do you have good reason to believe that if you run the code given millions of times, you'll detect a bias towards certain characters? Nothing you've said so far seems to be evidence of that.

Comment: @Jack: Thanks for your response. At this stage, I'm guided by the documentation for the default constructor which states `Creates a new random number generator. This constructor sets the seed of the random number generator to a value very likely to be distinct from any other invocation of this constructor.` While not foolproof, it would suggest that it is good enough. Would you agree with that assumption?